# How to get response header in c# Microsoft graph api request

Tags: c#, sharepoint, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to do [File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) operation in c# .net core using Microsoft graph API.
It is an asynchronous operation, and by doc, it says it returns a location in the [response header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response) to check the status of the operation,
Now the issue is I need its response header so that I can check the status of file copy operation but every time I am getting 'null' as value, I have tried following code,

```
DriveItem response = await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drive.Items[itemId]
                           .Copy(fileName, parentReference)
                           .Request()
                           .PostAsync();
```

The driveItem returns null but I think at least it should have returned the additional data-carrying response status and location.

When I use online [graph api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) it just works fine returning response and location, but it doesn't with graph client service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it is an issue with [`msgraph-sdk-dotnet`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet), at least it could be reproduced in `3.8.0` version, the error occurs while d*eserializing HTTP response*. Probably it would be more beneficial  to report it as a bug in referenced repository.

Meanwhile you could consider to construct a request for [`Copy a DriveItem` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and process response (including extracting `Location` header) as demonstrated below:

```
var message = graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drive.Items[itemId]
                .Copy(fileName, parentReference)
                .Request()
                .GetHttpRequestMessage();

message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
var body = new DriveItemCopyRequestBody {Name = fileName, ParentReference = parentReference};
message.Content = new StringContent(graphClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.SerializeObject(body));
message.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
var response = graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message).Result;
           
Console.Write(response.Headers.Location);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but also how can i set conflict state "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename", while using this type of solution