# How to get a response headers using Microsoft graph API

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I'm calling a Microsoft graph API to [create a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post). The response is a `202` with a `Location` header where I can get an [async operation details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamsasyncoperation).

How to get a response headers using `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client` module?

[A similar post using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335358/get-response-header-data-from-post-call) doesn't apply here. [This one also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62275489/how-to-get-response-header-in-c-sharp-microsoft-graph-api-request).

Here is my code with an attempt to get a raw response:

```
  const client = Client.init({
    authProvider: (done: any) => {
      done(null, accessToken);
    },
  });

  const response = client
    .api(`/teams`)
    .post(team, (error, response, responseRaw) => {
      console.log(error); // null
      console.log(response); // <empty string>
      console.log(responseRaw); // undefined
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the raw response set the responseType of a request to `ResponseType.RAW`

```
const response = client
    .api(`/teams`)
    .responseType(ResponseType.RAW)
    .post(team), (error, responseRaw) => {
      console.log(error);
      console.log(responseRaw); // responseRaw.status
    });
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/GettingRawResponse.md)

Then You can get a `Location` header like this:

```
const location = response.headers.get('Location');
```