# How to get a response headers using Microsoft graph API and MSGraphClientFactory

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, httpresponse, response-headers

I asking the exact question as this post here : [How to get a response headers using Microsoft graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66435746/how-to-get-a-response-headers-using-microsoft-graph-api)

The only difference (to me?) is that i'm using MSGraphClientFactory.getClient() from '@microsoft/sp-http' instead of { Client } from @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client.

My code so far :

```
const Rawresponse =  graphClient.api("/teams/" + groupID + '/archive')
    .version('v1.0')
    .responseType("raw")
    .post((error, responseRaw) => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(responseRaw);}
    ).then(response => console.log("then response : ", response.header));
```

[Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-archive?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) about the request itself.

Thanks in advance

PS : found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66435746/how-to-get-a-response-headers-using-microsoft-graph-api) along with the mentionned [doc](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/GettingRawResponse.md) but nothing work.
Afterthought : not quite suprising that the code in the client's doc doesn't work since I'm not using the client.

Comment: I understand that it's maybe dumb to use MSGraphClientFactory.getClient()  when @/microsoft-graph-client existe, but I don't know why and don't feel like updating the whole project without knowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !

```
const response = await graphClient
            .api("/teams/" + groupID + '/archive')
            .version('v1.0')
            .responseType("raw")
            .post({ "state": "archived" } , (error, resp, rawresponse) => {
                console.log("Error : ", error);
                console.log("Response : ", resp);
                console.log("RawResp :", rawresponse);
            });
        console.log("Location :",  response.headers.get("location"));
```

Apparently I needed to unclude `{"state" : "archived"}` as context of the post request.
I isn't stated in the doc so I'm not sure why